# How to add arguments in the big query table name when running queries via script?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have many tables which are following a certain pattern for example:- `project.dataset.ffm_{lang}_{event}`.

I want to create a duplicate table for all these tables via a script by adding clustering and partitioning into them.
I tried [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) which is supported by big query but we cannot add parameters to table name.

I also tried wildcard function but was not able to find any way to create a table of a particular pattern from another table which follow same kind of pattern.

The query i want to run is something like this:-

```
   create table `project.dataset.ffm_demo_{lang}_{event}`
   like `project.dataset.ffm_{lang}_{event}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can develop you own `Shell` script to create your tables dynamically based on a configured list, example :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u

# Declare and configure your lang_event list
declare -a StringArray=("Lang1_event1" "Lang2_event2")

# Iterate the string array using for loop
for val in "${StringArray[@]}"; do
  echo "Lang event : $val"
  
  # Use bq to create your current table
  bq mk \
    -t \
    --expiration 3600 \
    --description "This is my table" \
    --label organization:development \
    "mydataset.ff_demo_$val" \
    qtr:STRING,sales:FLOAT,year:STRING
done
```

Some explanations :

- Declare and configure your list of `lang_event`
- Loop over this list and for each element create a `BigQuery` table with `bq` and `gcloud` `cli`
- In my example I used a fake table schema `qtr:STRING,sales:FLOAT,year:STRING`, you have to adapt it for your table